# getting text from strings (parsing)

Tags: c++, parsing, formatting, equation

I am trying to make a c++ program that reads a .txt file and registers the coefficient of given equations.

example

```
2x+4y+5z = 10
```

I want to read that line from the .txt file and store those coefficients (2,4,5,10) in some array.
any suggestions?

My equations are always 3 variable equations.

Comment: Are your equations always modelled a specific way at all? Accounting for everything is a lot more work than, say, `2a+5h-7c... = 100`.

Comment: My immediate suggestion would be: what have you tried so far and what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: If it doesn't vary too much use regex, otherwise you're gonna need to do something much more complicated.

Comment: Parsing? Recursive descent. Fairly easy to implement by hand for such a simple grammar as a maths expression.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also, what is it you have problem with? Reading the file? Putting in array? The parsing? The calculations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own parser, because it could be very simple.

- Read the file line by line.
- Every time the line hits a variable(x,y,z) get the number before the variable.
- All the equations have the char *=*, so every time just parse until *=* and get the rest.
- One problem is that you also need to add if a number is positive or negative.

Comment: This also could help you http://speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_cpp/index.html